# FeignClient GET converted into POST

Tags: spring-cloud-feign

We have a quite simple `FeignClient`

```java
@GetMapping("/{id:.+}")
ResponseEntity<Resource> get(
    final HttpServletRequest request,
    @PathVariable(name = "id") final String id);
```

We are using thex Hoxton SR 4 spring cloud dependencies and
it uses the spring-cloud-openfeign 2.2.2.RELEASE.

For some reason this GET request is getting converted into a POST
request and we have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

Changing `{id:.+}` to `{id}` fixes the issue.